# Extra sections in screenplay

Tags: sectioning, screenplay

I am using `screenplay` package. It works fine, but currently lists scenes as 1, 2, 3... etc. Now I need to add some extra scenes in-between. Usually it would be done as scene 0A, 1A, 1B etc. How can I create a scene (section) with custom number?

Example script:

```
\documentclass{screenplay}

\begin{document}

\section{NEW YORK}
A great scene.

\section{TOKYO}
Even better scene.

\section{WHITE HOUSE}
The best scene.

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: Output]

I would like to add sections:

- `0A ROME`, before `1 NEW YORK`
- `1A THE HOTEL`, after `1 NEW YORK`
- `1B BASEMENT`, between `1A THE HOTEL` and `2 TOKYO`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Can you add a small working example that shows what you're doing?

Comment: Sure. Sorry about missing that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `screenplay` class loads `article` you can use `titlesec` to modify the sections. Here I've just made a format for `\subsection` to be the same as the `\section` format, and changed the numbering appropriately.

```
\documentclass{screenplay}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\Large}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\Alph{subsection}}
\begin{document}
\subsection{ROME}
This happens before

\section{NEW YORK}
A great scene.

\subsection{THE HOTEL}
This is a subscene

\subsection{THE BASEMENT}

\section{TOKYO}
Even better scene.

\section{WHITE HOUSE}
The best scene.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]